# join 3 tables using graphql query

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, express-graphql

I want to join 3 tables just like we do in mysql based on primary and foreign keys.

Can I do such using graphql(http://graphql.org/)
My table structure along with graphql query is below. Thanks

```
query($companyId:String){
  Data{
    reach{
     department {
       departmentId
       departmentName
       description
     }
      companyDepartment(companyId:$companyId) {
        primaryId
        departmentId
        companyId
        createdDate
        modifiedDate
        modifiedBy
      }
      company(companyId:$companyId) {
        companyId
        companyName
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You must break your mind and think in Graph way model :)

Type Company(node) <- CompanyDepartmentConection (name of connection edge) -> Type Department(node)

based on this very useful [article](https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/explaining-graphql-connections-c48b7c3d6976), anyway i do for you eg. Schema

## Concept

```
interface Node {
  id: ID!
  name: String
}

type Company implements Node {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  departmentsConnection: CompanyDepartmentConnection
}
type CompanyDepartmentConnection {
  pageInfo: PageInfo!
  edges: [CompanyDepartmentEdge]
}
type CompanyDepartmentEdge {
  cursor: String!
  node: Company
  linkedAt: DateTime
}
```